# How to properly close a sql connection on VB.net web app?

Tags: vb.net

I would like to know if my current way of opening and closing DB connection is correct.

In the execQuery function i added the DB connection after it executes. I call this function in the web form executeButton so i assume it closes.

In the case the try and catch exeption is triggered in the executeButton does it skip over the DB close?
Or does the DB connection closes first and then the try and catch exception is triggered?

**SQL Control**

```
Public Function ExecQuery(query As String) As DataTable

    Dim DBDT = New DataTable
    Using DBCon As New SqlConnection(ConStr),
            DBCmd As New SqlCommand(query, DBCon)
        Params.ForEach(Sub(p) DBCmd.Parameters.Add(p))
        Params.Clear()
        DBCon.Open()
        DBDT.Load(DBCmd.ExecuteReader)
        DBCon.Close()
        If DBCon.State = ConnectionState.Open Then DBCon.Close()
    End Using
    Return DBDT
End Function
```

**Web Form code**

```
Protected Sub ExecuteButton_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles ExecuteButton.Click
    Dim StoreID As Integer
    Dim TransID As Integer
    Dim RgstID As Integer
    Dim dt As DataTable

    If Not Integer.TryParse(StoreIDTextbox.Text, StoreID) Then
            MsgBox("Invalid input. Please enter both Store ID and Transaction ID.")
        Exit Sub

    End If

    If Not Integer.TryParse(TransactionIDTextbox.Text, TransID) Then
        MsgBox("Invalid input. Please enter both Store ID and Transaction ID.")
        Exit Sub
    End If

    SQL.AddParam("@Str_ID", StoreID)
    SQL.AddParam("@Tran_ID", TransID)

    'Rgst_ID Validation
    If RegisterIDTextbox.Text.Length = 0 Then
        SQL.AddParam("@Rgst_ID", "")
    ElseIf RegisterIDTextbox.Text.Length > 0 Then
        RgstID = Integer.Parse(RegisterIDTextbox.Text)
        SQL.AddParam("@Rgst_ID", RgstID)
    End If

    Try
        dt = SQL.ExecQuery("Select H.Emp_ID, H.Cust_ID, H.Rgst_ID, D.TRAN_LN_NUM, D.DISC_CD, D.AUTH_EMP_ID, D.ORIG_PRC, D.DISC_AMT, D.DISC_PCT, D.GL_ACCT_ID
                             From Transaction_Header H 
                             INNER Join LN_Detail L On (H.Str_ID = L.Str_ID And H.Rgst_ID = L.Rgst_ID And H.Tran_ID = L.Tran_ID)
                             INNER Join LN_Discount D ON (L.Str_ID = D.Str_ID And L.Rgst_ID = D.Rgst_ID And L.Tran_ID = D.Tran_ID And L.Tran_LN_Num = D.Tran_LN_Num)  
                             WHERE(H.Str_ID = @Str_ID)
                                And (H.Tran_ID = @Tran_ID)
                                And ((H.Rgst_ID = @Rgst_ID) Or (@Rgst_ID Is NULL Or @Rgst_ID = ''))")

        GridView1.DataSource = dt
        GridView1.DataBind()

    Catch ex As Exception

        MsgBox(ex.Message)
        Exit Sub

    End Try
```

Comment: You don't need these lines: `DBCon.Close() / If DBCon.State = ConnectionState.Open Then DBCon.Close()` because the `Using-End Using` block will automatically close it, even if there is an exception.

Answer (score 0):

The sequence of events is:

1. Error occurs
2. Exception is thrown from `ExecuteReader`
3. Exception is not caught within the `using` block within `ExecQuery`, so the block exits
4. Because the block exits, the connection is disposed and the connection is "closed" (returned to the connection pool)
5. The exception continues to bubble up out of `ExecQuery`
6. Except is caught in `ExecuteButton_Click`

Answer (score 0):

You don't show the definition of the rest of your SQL Control but you can get a DataAdapter to manage things for you

```
  
Function ExecQuery(sql as String)

    Dim dt = New DataTable
    Using da As New SqlDataAdapter(sql, constr)
        da.SelectCommand.Parameters.AddRange(Params.ToArray())
        Params.Clear()
        da.Fill(dt)
    End Using
    Return da
```

I think i'd probably jiggle things around so my whole SQLControl was disposable, have it have a DataAdapter, create it with the SQL to start (in a `Using`), then add the parameters directly, and fill.. could reuse it by keeping the SQL, changing the params, Filling again... When the `Using` exits, my SQLCOntrol is disposed and it could then dispose the adapter..

> In the case the try and catch exeption is triggered in the executeButton does it skip over the DB close? Or does the DB connection closes first and then the try and catch exception is triggered?

When code leaves a Using block, whatever was in the using (`da` in my case) is disposed. If an exception causes control to leave a Using block, then the resource is cleaned up as control leaves.

Internally a Using is implemented as a Try Finally (without a catch)

This:

```
Using x as New Y
   ... dodgy code ...
End Using
```

Becomes something like:

```
Dim x as New Y
Try
   ... dodgy code ...
Finally
  x.Dispose()
End Try
```